# Append to an existing batch file log but to a different column using the same batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to run my script and create a log file.  which it does.  I want to run that script a second time and append to the same log file but I want it to go to a new column.  Make it easier to compare the two results side by side.  Below is my script so far.  Thank you in advance.

```
echo off
color a
cls
@echo Welcome to the Ping Scan CheckList Script v2
echo.
@echo This script is going to expect three octets, and test the fourth.
@echo You can break the store i.p. into 4 octets. I.E. 10.x.yy.zz where x and yy equal the store number.
@echo Please begin entering the first three now.
ECHO.
SET/p first=First Octet:
SET/p second=Second Octet:
SET/p third=Third Octet:
@ECHO %DATE% %TIME% >>%USERPROFILE%\DESKTOP\%second%%third%-%USERNAME%-%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~10,4%.csv
SET t=0
:start
SET /a t=t+1
if %t%==2 GoTo start
if %t%==4 GoTo start
if %t%==15 GoTo start
if %t%==18 GoTo start
if %t%==19 GoTo start
if %t%==34 GoTo start
if %t%==43 GoTo start
if %t%==44 GoTo start
if %t%==45 GoTo start
if %t%==47 GoTo start
if %t%==48 GoTo start
if %t%==55 GoTo start
if %t%==59 GoTo start
if %t%==61 GoTo start
if %t%==64 GoTo start
if %t%==67 GoTo start
if %t%==69 GoTo start
if %t%==73 GoTo start
if %t%==74 GoTo start
if %t%==87 GoTo start
if %t%==89 GoTo start
if %t%==98 GoTo start
if %t%==99 GoTo start
if %t%==100 GoTo start
if %t%==101 GoTo start
if %t%==102 GoTo start
if %t%==103 GoTo start
if %t%==104 GoTo start
if %t%==105 GoTo start
if %t%==106 GoTo start
if %t%==107 GoTo start
if %t%==108 GoTo start
if %t%==109 GoTo start
if %t%==110 GoTo start
if %t%==111 GoTo start
if %t%==112 GoTo start
if %t%==113 GoTo start
if %t%==114 GoTo start
if %t%==115 GoTo start
if %t%==116 GoTo start
if %t%==117 GoTo start
if %t%==118 GoTo start
if %t%==119 GoTo start
if %t%==120 GoTo start
if %t%==121 GoTo start
if %t%==122 GoTo start
if %t%==123 GoTo start
if %t%==124 GoTo start
if %t%==125 GoTo start
if %t%==126 GoTo start
if %t%==127 GoTo start
if %t%==128 GoTo start
if %t%==132 GoTo start
if %t%==133 GoTo start
if %t%==134 GoTo start
if %t%==158 GoTo start
if %t%==159 GoTo start
if %t%==166 GoTo start
if %t%==170 GoTo start
if %t%==179 GoTo start
if %t%==185 GoTo start
if %t%==191 GoTo start
if %t%==192 GoTo start
if %t%==194 GoTo start
if %t%==195 GoTo start
if %t%==198 GoTo start
if %t%==199 GoTo start
if %t%==202 GoTo start
if %t%==203 GoTo start
if %t%==204 GoTo start
if %t%==207 GoTo start
if %t%==208 GoTo start
if %t%==209 GoTo start
if %t%==212 GoTo start
if %t%==213 GoTo start
if %t%==214 GoTo start
echo Pinging .%t%
ping -w 100 -l 1 %first%.%second%.%third%.%t% > nul
if %errorlevel%==0 echo %first%.%second%.%third%.%t% is UP! >> %USERPROFILE%\DESKTOP\%second%%third%-%USERNAME%-%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~10,4%.csv
if %errorlevel%==1 echo ****%first%.%second%.%third%.%t%**** is DOWN! >> %USERPROFILE%\DESKTOP\%second%%third%-%USERNAME%-%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~10,4%.csv
IF %t%==217 GoTo finish
Goto start
:finish
@echo The script is done, you can find the full log on your desktop
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

First, build a list with your desired IP`s (last octett), like this:

```
IP
1
3
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
16
(and so on)
```

as a base for the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
break>b.csv
set "base=192.168.178"
for /f "tokens=1,*delims=," %%i in (a.csv) do (
 if "%%i"=="IP" (
   echo %%i,%%j,%time:~0,5%>>b.csv
 ) else (
   ping -n 1 -w 100 -4 %base%.%%i|find "TTL=" >nul && set "state=UP" || set "state=DOWN"
   echo %%i,%%j,!state!>>b.csv
 )
)
type b.csv>a.csv
type a.csv
```

I shortened the filenames and strings to keep the code readable.

There is a small issue with the first iteration (two consecutive commas), which could be corrected with another `if` - but it's "self correcting" with the next iteration.

Note: The errorlevel of `ping` is not reliable, therefore you should look for "TTL=".